# How to make image source change after handle without display another one on canvas output (OpenCV.js)

Tags: opencv, ionic-framework, image-processing

I am using OpenCV.js in Ionic 3 to make a scanner app.
I have a .ts file with rotate function like this:

```
rotateRight() {
let src = cv.imread('img');
let dst = new cv.Mat();
let dsize = new cv.Size(src.rows, src.cols);
let center = new cv.Point(src.cols / 2, src.rows / 2);
let M = cv.getRotationMatrix2D(center, -90, 1);
cv.warpAffine(src, dst, M, dsize, cv.INTER_LINEAR, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, new cv.Scalar());
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
src.delete(); dst.delete(); M.delete();
}
```

And I have code like this in .html file with img source to get and canvas to display new image after processing:

```
<img id="img" [src]="picture" *ngIf="picture" /> 
<canvas id="canvasOutput" ></canvas>
```

My problem is I just want to display only one image in my .html file, I want after processing the new image will display in the img source from the begin instead of having another display like canvas.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking I found the answer by myself.

Firstly, get element canvasOutput and img from HTML, then change image's source to canvasOutput with base64 format:

```
var canvasOutput = document.getElementById('canvasOutput') as HTMLCanvasElement; 
let picture = document.getElementById("img") as HTMLImageElement;
picture.src = canvasOutput.toDataURL();
```

Lastly set 's style to visibility: hidden to hide canvas tag.